# How to check bluetooth status via terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bluetooth

I am looking for a way to check to see if the bluetooth is enabled or disabled on my laptop via the terminal. Is there a command that I can use to find this information

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/591803/how-to-check-bluetooth-version-on-my-laptop

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In addition to checking for the service you can use the command

```
hcitool dev
```

that will return all devices turned on.

Comment: I suppose I needed to word my question better. This answer provides me with what I need. With this I can see if my device is on or off based on whether or not it shows up. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: `hcitool con` worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

## More information with `hciconfig -a`

`hciconfig -a` provides way more information, including the Bluetooth version.

```
$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DC:70:13  ACL MTU: 310:10  SCO MTU: 64:8
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:1013 acl:0 sco:0 events:60 errors:0
    TX bytes:4890 acl:0 sco:0 commands:60 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x5b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'hostname'
    Class: 0x1c0104
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Desktop workstation
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x22bb
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x22bb
    Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
```

Answer (score 18):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, You can run this command to see the status of bluetooth

```
sudo service bluetooth status
```

after you enter your password, you should see something like

bluetooth is running

Comment: Regardless of whether or not the bluetooth is on i get the same message from that command:        
`bluetooth start/running, process 1132`

Comment: The Bluetooth icon disappeared.I get the following message. Can anyone please help me what this mean?

Comment: ashoke@Dell-3470:~$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service

Mar 09 15:16:42 Dell-3470 bluetoothd[1141]: Starting SDP server
Mar 09 15:16:42 Dell-3470 bluetoothd[1141]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14>
Mar 09 16:35:14 Dell-3470 bluetoothd[1141]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Mar 09 16:35:59 Dell-3470 bluetoothd[1141]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Mar 09 16:36:01 Dell-3470 bluetoothd[1141]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Mar 09 16:36:04 Dell-3470 bluetoothd[1141]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
lines 1-20/20 (END)

Comment: This answer was correct for me. I wanted to see if it was active and it said so, I think this answers the question. Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is to use the command `hciconfig`. It will list clearly the interfaces, and you will see by the marker "RUNNING" or "DOWN" what is their current status.

Answer (score 5):

`rfkill` will show you a list of network devices and if they are on or off.

Answer (score 5):

With [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/): Using `bluetoothctl` (*interactive bluetooth control tool*), which gives you a terminal with `show` and these other commands:

```
[bluetooth]# help
Menu main:
Available commands:
-------------------
advertise                        Advertise Options Submenu
scan                             Scan Options Submenu
gatt                             Generic Attribute Submenu
list                             List available controllers
show [ctrl]                      Controller information
select <ctrl>                    Select default controller
devices                          List available devices
paired-devices                   List paired devices
system-alias <name>              Set controller alias
reset-alias                      Reset controller alias
power <on/off>                   Set controller power
pairable <on/off>                Set controller pairable mode
discoverable <on/off>            Set controller discoverable mode
discoverable-timeout [value]     Set discoverable timeout
agent <on/off/capability>        Enable/disable agent with given capability
default-agent                    Set agent as the default one
advertise <on/off/type>          Enable/disable advertising with given type
set-alias <alias>                Set device alias
scan <on/off>                    Scan for devices
info [dev]                       Device information
pair [dev]                       Pair with device
trust [dev]                      Trust device
untrust [dev]                    Untrust device
block [dev]                      Block device
unblock [dev]                    Unblock device
remove <dev>                     Remove device
connect <dev>                    Connect device
disconnect [dev]                 Disconnect device
menu <name>                      Select submenu
version                          Display version
quit                             Quit program
exit                             Quit program
help                             Display help about this program
export                           Print environment variables
```

---

With [bluez-tools](https://github.com/khvzak/bluez-tools): `bt-*` (`apropos bt-`) like `bt-device`, a bluetooth device manager.

Comment: Thanks! This also works with Fedora 37!